# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined when deploying on server both java and angular2

Tags: angular

When I run my Angular 2 project, it works completely locally but when I try to deploy to a server, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

[image]

node version : v7.10.1
npm version : 4.2.0

Comment: this is not java related. your angular variable is not defined and you're calling one of it's members. this is basically the same as a NullPointerException in Java

Comment: Please show the Angular's code.

Comment: provide your node, npm and ng version.

Comment: which file of code..?/

Comment: There's a problem with your vendor.bundle.js which is not loaded, how did you deploy your app ?

Comment: i m trying to run spring boot and angular 2 project on single port

Comment: i m putting my dist file in static folder of spring boot project. and deploy in tomcat server

Comment: share your code angular as well as spring